# Java - Http Framework to Post XML Files

Tags: java, jquery, xml, jakarta-ee, post

I want to learn Java / Java EE and therefore decide to rewrite my JavaScript application build in jQuery, which can send XML files against a REST Api.

Simplified it looks like:

```
var Core = {
    sendData : function() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url : "/test",
            method : "POST",
            contentType : "application/xml; charset=utf-8",
            data : JSON.strinigfy(xmlFeed),
            success : function(data) {
                // TODO
            },
            error : function() {
                // TODO
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I want to build a Java application, which can POST XML files against a REST Api.
For the REST Api it is nescessary, that the XML file will be post as Request Payload. I tried Jsoup, but actually it can not send XML files in this way. Is there any Java framework, which makes it easier for me to build my first Java application?

Answer (score -1):

I found [an article](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/09/simple-rest-client-in-java.html) which might help you. It suggests Apache HttpClient or Jersey client.  The HttpClient is probably better focused on your specific need because Jersey is primarily for server-side REST implementations, and you seem to need just a REST client.  I also found [Resty](https://beders.github.io/Resty/Resty/Overview.html), which is probably newer than the article, and seems promising.

Answer (score -1):

To make your RESTful web service you can use:

- Jersey (https://jersey.java.net/);
- RESTEasy (http://resteasy.jboss.org/);

I haven't used RESTEasy, but I can say that Jersey supports XML, with serialization, out of the box. Take a look at the documentation (https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#xml).

Or, you can use some big frameworks, that will help you with the architecture of your aplication. To name ones:

- Spring (https://spring.io/);
- Play (https://www.playframework.com/);
- Struts (http://struts.apache.org/);

Most of them are MVC frameworks, but you can easily build RESTful web services with them.